# How do I make a button add a day to a datefield

Tags: javascript, oop, extjs, extjs4

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this the 'right' way - or at least make it work, and I am by no means an expert on either js or Extjs.

### Goal

Create a panel with a datepicker, and simple controls to go to the given date or go to the previous/next day made in Extjs 4. It is to be a part of a php application for displaying a given days schedule in an html table. The only thing this question concerns is how to create the datepicker properly in Extjs.

I've taken a screenshot of the Extjs part of my application to give an idea of the usage:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK59V.png

### Problem

I think I've made the basic structure of the code, but I'm having trouble getting the prev and next buttons to add or substract a day from the `datefield`. 
I've made two functions,`prevDate()` and `nextDate()`, within the datefield item to show what I want to achieve, but I'm pretty sure thats not how to do it.

How would I go about that? If I'm supposed to do it with my own functions, where do I add them and how do I add them?

I've got a refference to the `datefield` inside the handler for the `prev` and `next` buttons, but I'd rather not do it this way - any suggestion on how to design this better?

Since this is some of my first experience with Extjs 4, I'd also like to do it the 'right' way, or at least not make something too crude.

### Code

```
var datePanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
    },
    renderTo: 'date-controls',
    width: 258,
    height: 43,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '60%',
        name: 'datepicker',
        id: 'extDatepicker',
        cls: 'datepicker',
        value: new Date(),
        handler: function(picker, date) {
            picker.value = date; 
        },

        /*These two functions doesn't work because they don't actually 
          have a reference to the picker - Is it event the correct way 
          to add functions to the datefield?*/
        nextDate: function(picker, date) {
            picker.value = Ext.Date.add(picker.value, Ext.Date.DAY, 1);
        },
        prevDate: function(picker, date) {
            picker.value = Ext.Date.add(picker.value, Ext.Date.DAY, -1);
        }
    },{
        xtype: 'button',
        name: 'go',
        text: 'GO',
        scope: this, 
        cls: 'ext-button-go',
        handler: function() {
            //TODO
        }
    },{
        xtype: 'button',
        name: 'prev',
        text: '<',
        cls: 'ext-button',
        handler: function() {

                    /*This looks crude and wrong, 
                      I would much rather pass a reference or something*/
            var datefield = datePanel.items.getAt(0);
            console.log(datefield);
            datefield.prevDate();
        }
    },{
        xtype: 'button',
        name: 'next',
        text: '>',
        cls: 'ext-button',
        handler: function() {
            var datefield = datePanel.items.getAt(0);
            console.log(datefield);
            datefield.nextDate();
        }
    }]
});
```

I'm currently doing the [MVC tutorial from Sencha](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/application_architecture) in my spare time, but I'm having a hard time translating what I'm doing there to something of this small scale. It seems to be too complex for what I'm trying to achieve here, no? 
Feel free to point out better ways to go about this.

Any input is very much appreciated.

---

Edit:
I'd totally forgotten about the `datefield.setValue(Date)` function, and now I'm able to go to the previous or next date by setting the `handler` of the `prev` and `next` buttons like this:

```
xtype: 'button',
name: 'prev',
text: '<',
cls: 'ext-button',
handler: function() {
    var datefield = datePanel.items.getAt(0);
    datefield.setValue(Ext.Date.add(datefield.value, Ext.Date.DAY, -1));
}
```

I'm still unsure if this is the right way to do this. It feels kind of 'dirty'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to perform date calculations...
you must to convert it first to timestamp format. and convert it back the result to date format...

here my [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammad_erdin/rvqwd/)

and if you want to run some of your custom functions, 
dont append it in your config component (even it may work).. 
i will prefer to make my own instance class. take look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammad_erdin/rvqwd/3/)

and one more thing,.... button doesn't have `name` config.
have you read the doc api ???

Comment: I like your date calculation because they are easy to read, though mine should be good too - [see the example under the `add` method in the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Date)

Thank you for the class instance example! It really helped me understand how to create my own datefields and other classes with custom functions!

Comment: While it wasn't your answer that led me to my solution, I find your answer the most correct answer to my question and the most relevant for other people stumbling unto it.

To make this answer even more useful, you could post some snippets from the class instance Fiddler example, so the information is here  if the Fiddler links stops working.

Answer (score 2):

I think part of your problem is you are trying to set a `value` property instead of calling `Ext.picker.Date`'s `setValue` method.

I'd also rewrite your handlers to look like this:

```
handler: function() {
    var datefield = this.up('panel').getComponent('extDatepicker');
    console.log(datefield);
    datefield.nextDate();
}
```

Also, FYI, you can use `itemId` instead of `id` when setting IDs for a component. `itemId` is relative to the container, whereas `id` is a global ID that is searchable across the entire page. Thus multiple `itemId`s with the same value can coexist in the same app, provided they aren't in the same container.

`up` allows you to jump from the current button up to the panel using the `xtype` to search for a container, and then you go over to the date picker with `getComponent`.

Comment: Thank you, the `setValue` part of your comment made me *doh*.
My current construction with the `prevDate()` and `nextDate()` function still doesn't work because it doesn't even have a reference to `picker`. It throws _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined_.

Got it working by setting the values directly inside the `handler`